# Change the properties file

Tags: java, apache, log4j

I have properties file as below

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

I want to change the log level in this file so i write below line in java file

```
logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
```

this will only change my log level at run time what if i want to change the log level permanently in properties file?

Comment: Have you tried just changing `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG` to `log4j.rootLogger=FATAL` ?

Comment: yes but i want it permanent

Comment: Changing the .properties file will be permanent. Whenever the application starts up, the settings in the properties file will be effective.

Comment: I want to change it from java file I am using same properties file for log4j and log4cxx in c++ thats why i want it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `java.util.Properties` class. The class allows to load properties from a file, change it, then save to a file.